# $(B^{-1}AB)(B^{-1}AB)^n=B^{-1}A^{n+1}B$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A,B$ be $n\times n$ matrices in a field $K$, and assume that $B$ is invertible.
Show that

$(B^{-1}AB)^n=(BA^nB)$

for all positive integers.

Solution Induction. The statement is true when $n=1$. Suppose the statement is true for an integer $n$; then we have

$(B^{-1}A)^{n+1}=(B^{-1}AB)(B^{-1}AB)^n=B^{-1}A^{n+1}B$

which ends the proof.***Rami Sharkarchi, Solutions Manual for Lang´s Linear Algebra***

**Question:**

How does the author knows $(B^{-1}AB)(B^{-1}AB)^n=B^{-1}A^{n+1}B$? How does the author know that only the $A$ is going to multiply?

Comment: He doesn't; he multiplies it out, recalling that $BB^{-1}=I$.

Comment: He is using the **associativity** of the matrix product!

Comment: There is a typo in the formula of the second line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By induction hypothesis, $(B^{-1}AB)^n= B^{-1}A^nB$

Now he wants to prove that $(B^{-1}AB)^{n+1}=B^{-1}A^{n+1}B$ using induction hypothesis.

\begin{align}(B^{-1}AB)^{n+1}&=(B^{-1}AB)(B^{-1}AB)^n\\&=(B^{-1}AB)(B^{-1}A^nB)\\&=B^{-1}A(BB^{-1})A^nB\\&=B^{-1}A^nB \end{align}

where the second equality is due to induction hypothesis and the third equality is due to $BB^{-1}=I$.

Answer (score 1):

By induction hypothesis, we have $$(B^{-1}AB)(B^{-1}AB)^n=(B^{-1}AB)(B^{-1}A^nB)=B^{-1}A(BB^{-1})A^nB=B^{-1}AA^nB=B^{-1}A^{n+1}B,$$
where we have used associativity and $BB^{-1}=I$.